# Java Spring: getting the generic type

Tags: java, spring, generics

I have a parameterized class that implements the `FactoryBean` interface:

```
public class DogFactory<T extends Dog> implements FactoryBean<T> {

    // ...

}
```

What I want is to use this factory for spawning objects of different classes (all of these classes extend `Dog`). So I imagined that I could do something like the following:

```
public class ShepherdService {

    private DogFactory<Shepherd> shepherdFactory;

    public ShepherdService(
        @Autowired
        DogFactory<Shepherd> shepherdFactory
    ) {
        this.shepherdFactory = shepherdFactory;
    }

    // ...

}
```

Alas, I get the following error: `Couldn't autowire. No beans of DogService<Shepherd> type found.` :-(

How to inject it and use as `DogFactory<Shepherd>` or `DogFactory<Corgi>` (not just `DogFactory`)?

And another question. I also need to pass the `Shepherd.class` (or `Corgi.class`) to this bean, so it could "know" at run-time, objects of what exactly class should it produce. Is there a way to do that?

Or should I forget about `FactoryBean` and instantiate the factory as a regular class? Of course, I could do it this way:

```
    DogFactory<Shepherd> shepherdFactory = new DogFactory<Shepherd>(Shepherd.class);
```

It would work perfectly, but I'd like to use `FactoryBean` as I use it for other factories in this project, so I would like to stick to `FactoryBean`.

Thanks in advance!

### Update 1

Maybe I should clarify it more precise. What I need is a factory that could produce objects of different classes. All these classes should be extensions of the certain class (e.g., `Shepherd` and `Corgi` - all these classes extend `Dog`). And as the final result I actually need something like that:

```
public class DogService<T extend Dog> {

    private DogFactory<T> dogFactory;

    @Autowired
    public DogService(DogFactory<T> dogFactory) {
        this.dogFactory = dogFactory;
    }

    public T spawnDog(Color color) {
        T dog = DogFactory.getObject(color);
        return dog;
    }

}
```

But it seems that I can't make a "universal" factory with the `FactoryBean` interface, so I can't do something like that:

```
public class DogFactory<T extends Dog> implements FactoryBean<T> {
   // ...
}
```

Instead of that I have to do something like the following:

```
public class ShepherdFactory implements FactoryBean<Shepherd> {
   // ...
}
public class CorgiFactory implements FactoryBean<Corgi> {
   // ...
}
```

Is that true?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> What I want is to instantiate this factory in another class

If you mean *"having the factory injected in the class instead of the bean it creates"*, you could inject the factory by prefixing its name with an ampersand:

```java
public class ShepherdService {

    private DogFactory<Shepherd> shepherdFactory;

    @Qualifier("&dogFactory")
    public ShepherdService(DogFactory<Shepherd> shepherdService) {
        this.shepherdService = shepherdService;
    }
}
```

From the Spring documentation ([section 3.8.3](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/spring-framework-reference/html/ch03s08.html)):

> When you need to ask a container for an actual FactoryBean instance
>   itself, not the bean it produces, you preface the bean id with the
>   ampersand symbol & (without quotes) when calling the getBean method of
>   the ApplicationContext. So for a given FactoryBean with an id of
>   myBean, invoking getBean("myBean") on the container returns the
>   product of the FactoryBean, and invoking getBean("&myBean") returns
>   the FactoryBean instance itself.

Furthermore, my guess is that the FactoryBean is not picked up as a Spring bean as your snippets did not contain an `XML config` section, a `Java config` section, or a `@Component` annotation. I would explicitly declare the factory bean in a `@Configuration` annotated class, or annotate the factory class with `@Component`.

**[edit]**

> But it seems that I can't make a "universal" factory with the
>   FactoryBean interface, so I can't do something like that:

You could still have a single `Configuration` class in which you declare all the factory beans.

```java
@Configuration
public class DogFactoryConfig {

    @Bean
    public DogFactory<Shepherd> shepherdFactory() {
        return new DogFactory<Shepherd>();
    }

    @Bean
    public DogFactory<Corgi> corgiFactory() {
        return new DogFactory<Corgi>();
    }
}
```

And remove the @Component annotation from your `DogFactory` if it is present.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems my question wasn't clear enough, that's my fault, I'm sorry for that. Would you, please, be so kind as to look into the update if you have some spare time? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reply to your updated question.

Comment: Many thanks to you for your kind help, @Michiel. It seems I've found one more solution, I'll describe it soon.

Comment: Good to hear that you've found a solution!